# Ajax Include Data In Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently i'm retrieve data from api. The data contains id and charity_name. It must be on dropdown list. Currently successful to show the charity name in the dropdown list but stuck on the id. How can i include the id in the option in the dropdown list?

```js
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://ayambrand-com-my-v1.cloudaccess.host/administrator/index.php?option=com_echarity&format=raw&task=api.get_charities', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
     $.each(data, function(index, element) {
      $('#list').append($('<option>', {
       text: element.charity_name
      }));
     });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form>
    <table class="a">
     <tr>
     <td>
      <select id="list">

      </select>
     </td>
     </tr>

    </table>
     <table class="b">
     <tr>
     <td>
     <span>Content</span>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: You want id as a value in option ?

Comment: It should look like this

<select>
<option value="<id>"><charity name></option>
</select>

How can i do like this?

Comment: @Mohd Shafiq Check my answer

Comment: Like this ? Are you  want to bind company  and ID both in dropdown list ?

Comment: @Mohd Shafiq Did you check my answer, it will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `value: id` in e.g

```
$('#list').append($('<option>', {
         text: element.charity_name,
         value: element.id
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you

```js
$(function(){

//place this inside your ajax success
var data=[{id:1,charity_name:"One"},{id:2,charity_name:"two"}];
var html="";
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    html+="<option value="+element.id+">"+element.charity_name+"</option>";
});
$('#list').append(html);
          
    /*$.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://ayambrand-com-my-v1.cloudaccess.host/administrator/index.php?option=com_echarity&format=raw&task=api.get_charities', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
         
        }
    });*/


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
  <table class="a">
    <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="list">

      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
   <table class="b">
   <tr>
   <td>
   <span>Content</span>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
</div>
```